# MySQL case insensitive search in UTF8 processing latin uppercase/lowercase

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, latin1

folks.
I'm new at MySQL programming and I've tried all things to manage this.

I would like to do a insensitive search with/without accents, lowercases or uppercases and all return the same results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo_pesquisado LIKE '%termo_pesquisado%' ORDER BY campo_pesquisado ASC
```

So, in my DB (MyISAM - collation utf8_general_ci) I have this

```
+---------+--------+
| campo_pesquisado |
+---------+--------+
|   SÃ£o Paulo     |
|   SÃƒO JOÃƒO     |
```

I would like to type termo_pesquisado (keywords) = São Paulo, Sao Paulo, SÃO PAULO or any combination of 'São Paulo' to get the return of **SÃ£o Paulo** (that in browser shows correctly - São Paulo) from the database.

**THE PROBLEM**

If I type "são paulo, SãO PAULO or any combination with the "**ã**" lowercase works. It's because the UTF-8 respective code for **ã** is **Ã£**. If I search for SÃO PAULO, the Ã letter become **Ãƒ** the full word will be **SÃƒO PAULO** that is clearly not equal to **SÃ£o Paulo**.

**TRYING**

To solve this I tried this code bellow, but is not working for me.

```
 SELECT *, CONVERT(CAST( campo_pesquisado AS BINARY) USING utf8) FROM table WHERE CONVERT(CAST( campo_pesquisado AS BINARY) USING utf8) LIKE '%termo_pesquisado%' ORDER BY campo_pesquisado ASC
```

**IMPORTANT**

I can't change my collation. We have to use utf8 as char encode for the tables. Its better for multilanguage purposes.

I'm using PHP (5.5) and the last version of MySQL.

Comment: Isn't the utf8 character for `ã`, `ã`? Note that `collation` and `character set` are different separate things. It sounds like you aren't in utf8 somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try this : SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY campo_pesquisado = 'termo_pesquisado' ORDER BY campo_pesquisado ASC

Comment: @chris85 I will try to follow the possible answer in **UTF-8 all the way through**

Comment: @chris85 - If you follow this [link](http://site112.com/converter-latin-utf) you will see that the character for ã is Ã£ (8859-1 to UTF-8).

Comment: @krish I tried but not worked. :(

Comment: @chris85 The **ã** is ISO-8859-1, when we use the [utf8_encode php function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) the **ã** turns in **Ã£**

Comment: Where are you in ISO, why not in UTF8? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm

Comment: @chris85 our main language is Portuguese. The browser translate automatically the DB characters from UTF8 to ISO. When the user types something he types with an keyboard that has **ã** (keys with accents). The codes are converted when the user send the info (Eg.: forms, inputs ...)

Comment: Look through that utf8 thread, you should have utf8 for all your pages; from the user input to the database write.

Comment: Search for Mojibake.